# How to prevent /var/log/mail.log from inflating?

Tags: ubuntu, sendmail

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 (oneiric).

`/var/log/mail` keeps inflating on my server:

```
Aug  5 10:48:25 domU-12-31-39-0B-C4-54 sm-msp-queue[13360]: q71He1xw027248: to=postmaster, delay=3+17:03:10, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=23074446, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by [127.0.0.1]
Aug  5 10:48:25 domU-12-31-39-0B-C4-54 sm-msp-queue[13308]: q717K1wk024979: to=postmaster, delay=4+03:23:18, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=25779463, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by [127.0.0.1]
Aug  5 10:48:25 domU-12-31-39-0B-C4-54 sm-msp-queue[13360]: q71He1xx027248: to=postmaster, delay=3+17:03:10, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=23075343, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by [127.0.0.1]
...
```

I am not using sendmail directly, and would prefer to disable it.

It seems sendmail cannot start:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/sendmail start 
* Starting Mail Transport Agent (MTA) sendmail
451 4.0.0 /etc/mail/sendmail.cf: line 100: fileclass: 
cannot open '/etc/mail/local-host-names': Group writable directory
```

I believe I have the correct permissions:

```
$ ls -ld /etc/mail/local-host-names
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 52 2011-12-04 06:58 /etc/mail/local-host-names
```

But ... are the permissions on the parent folder ok?

```
g$ ls -ld / /etc /etc/mail
drwxr-xr-x 23 root  root  4096 2012-05-23 08:38 /
drwxrwxr-x 99 root  root  4096 2012-08-05 07:29 /etc
drwxr-sr-x  7 smmta smmsp 4096 2011-12-04 06:58 /etc/mail
```

I would want to either fix sendmail, or disable it. I tried:

```
$ sudo update-rc.d sendmail disable
update-rc.d: warning: sendmail start runlevel arguments (none) do not match LSB Default-Start values (2 3 4 5)
update-rc.d: warning: sendmail stop runlevel arguments (none) do not match LSB Default-Stop values (1)
 Disabling system startup links for /etc/init.d/sendmail ...
 Removing any system startup links for /etc/init.d/sendmail ...
   /etc/rc0.d/K19sendmail
   /etc/rc1.d/K19sendmail
   /etc/rc2.d/K79sendmail
   /etc/rc3.d/K79sendmail
   /etc/rc4.d/K79sendmail
   /etc/rc5.d/K79sendmail
   /etc/rc6.d/K19sendmail
 Adding system startup for /etc/init.d/sendmail ...
   /etc/rc0.d/K19sendmail -> ../init.d/sendmail
   /etc/rc1.d/K19sendmail -> ../init.d/sendmail
   /etc/rc6.d/K19sendmail -> ../init.d/sendmail
   /etc/rc2.d/K79sendmail -> ../init.d/sendmail
   /etc/rc3.d/K79sendmail -> ../init.d/sendmail
   /etc/rc4.d/K79sendmail -> ../init.d/sendmail
   /etc/rc5.d/K79sendmail -> ../init.d/sendmail
```

but my mail.log still gets the same errors.

Additional links I looked into:

- http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/servers/184133-connection-refused-127-0-0-1-mail-logs.html
- https://serverfault.com/questions/314429/cannot-open-etc-mail-trusted-users-group-writable-directory

Answer (score 3):

I believe you don't have the right permissions on /etc. It too cannot be group-writable.
Try

```
sudo chmod g-w /etc
```

Does that help?

Comment: This helped me start sendmail, but the logs still are flowing at a huge rate (~ 10 each second). Perhaps I need to wait for the queue to be processed or restart the server. I still don't understand how to disable sendmail altogether.